# Building OpenCV 2.4.5 in android ADT: "ndk-build" not found in PATH

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to follow [this OpenCV document](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) to import OpenCV sample projects into the android ADT, and am getting the now infamous "Program "C:\android\android-ndk-r8d-windows\ndk-build" not found in PATH" error. My OS is Windows 7 and I use cygwin for any Linux-like commands.

Please note: I *already* downloaded the NDK package, and *already* set the value of NDKROOT to be my NDK root folder. I setup NDKROOT both as a system-wide environmental variable, and as an ADT's C/C++ Build environment variable, as shown below:

[image]

In my NDK root folder, I made identical copies of the file "ndk-build.cmd", and renamed them as "ndk-build" and "ndk-build.sh" respectively. I chmod+x to all three ndk-build* files.

Now what happens is really puzzling: If I specify the C/C++ Build command to be ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build or ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.sh, I get the error "Program "C:\android\android-ndk-r8d-windows\ndk-build" not found in PATH". However, if I specify it to be ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd, ADT apparently finds it, but tries to run it as a Windows command, not as a bash script, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

The only way I can build a project, is to open a cygwin terminal, cd to the sample project folder, and run the script (either ndk-build or ndk-build.sh), like this:

[image]

I googled around for a solution. Although there are lots of "ndk-build.cmd not found in PATH" questions, I have not seen a case like mine. What is happening? I might also post my question to the openCV forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the command that your Eclipse tries to run (when using the `${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd` version) is `C:\\android\\android-ndk-r8d-windows\\ndk-build.cmd`, which is apparently correct.

The problem is that your `ndk-build.cmd` is not a windows command file. And it should be. I just downloaded the Windows version of the ndk-r8e and the ndk-build.cmd file is copied [here](http://pastebin.com/PphebgzL).

Try to download the ndk again or to modify your cmd file.

Comment: Your copy of ndk-build.cmd works. Thanks! It looks like somehow my original ndk-build.cmd got replaced by its bash script counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the  `${NDKROOT}` variable (which is the folder in which the NDK is located) the same way you did with the `PATH` variable